# Why am I not receiving token on backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to separate the backend from the frontend of a web app I'm building, both the back and the frontend are written using asp.net core 2.2 (i know I could have used another framework for the frontend but it would've take more time since before separating them, the project was mostly done).

I'm using RestSharp to make the requests to the backend and I've been trying to pass the jwt token without being successful.

It works fine as it should when I make the request in swagger or postman so I know that the problem might be in the frontend app.

This is how I'm doing the request

```
        var client = new RestClient(BaseAddress.Url);
        var req = new RestRequest("api/client/dash");
        req.Parameters.Clear();
        req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        string bearer = "bearer " + token;
        req.AddHeader("Authorization", bearer);
        //req.AddParameter("Authorization", "bearer " + token, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        var res = client.Get(req);
```

I have tried different methods of adding the Authorization header without being successful.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and what might be the problem??

Comment: Since you're using Postman and RestSharp, can you get the C# code from Postman and verify what is missing?

Comment: I already tried that and it still didn't work. This is the code that i got from postman

        var client = new RestClient(BaseAddress.Url + "/api/client/dash");
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:42069/api/client/dash");
 client.Timeout = -1;
 var req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 req.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
 IRestResponse res = client.Execute(req);

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "bearer " in your Postman?. Some users complain that when changing from "bearer " to "Bearer " seems to work from some servers

Comment: Yes im using bearer token in postman and i've already tried both bearer and Bearer and still doesn't work.